# Read binary plist into NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, plist

Is there simple way to parse the binary plist file into the NSDictionary representation?
I am searching something like that:

```
NSString* strings = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL: ... encoding: NSUnicodeStringEncoding error: ...];
NSMutableDictionary* pairs = (NSMutableDictionary*)[strings propertyListFromStringsFileFormat];
```

Using this code caused the exception while parsing the binary plist file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you looking for `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:]`?

Answer (score 3):

Considering a file called `DataStorageFile.plist`, you can use:

```
NSString *dataPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DataStorageFile" ofType:@"plist"];
self.data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:dataPath];
```

If you want an array:

```
self.data = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:dataPath];
```