# display data from plist to tableCell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, plist

i have a pilist whose screen shot is given below:

[image: plist]

i want to display its data in table cell. my code is

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection: (NSInteger)section
{
    return 2;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"datalist" ofType:@"plist"];

// Load the file content and read the data into arrays
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
tableData = [dict objectForKey:@"title"];
    thumbnails = [dict objectForKey:@"Subtitle"];
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",thumbnails];
return cell;
}
```

I am getting this output:

[image: Output screen]

Comment: See this [Read binary plist into NSDictionary][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622037/read-binary-plist-into-nsdictionary

Comment: i recheck the code and modified now i get this output. I can;t figure out whats happening  http://screencast.com/t/fWvPoroH9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code `thumbnails = [dict objectForKey:@"Subtitle"];` will return an NSArray.
What you should be doing is iterating through this array and getting each item.

Like `cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[thumbnails objectAtIndex:0]]` or `cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[thumbnails objectAtIndex:1]]`

Or maybe something like this

`cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[thumbnails objectAtIndex:0], [thumbnails objectAtIndex:0]]`

Try it.

Comment: @UnicoRahul : As per your plist `thumbnails` should be a array, but it seems like you have declared this variable as NSDictionary. try changing the type of `thumbnails`

Comment: Just `NSLog(@"%@", thumbnails);` and check contents of `thumbnails`. This would make it clear of how to fetch your values

Answer (score 1):

Try This One:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"datalist.plist"];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath])
{
    plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"datalist" ofType:@"plist"];
}

NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
tableData = [dict objectForKey:@"title"];
thumbnails = [dict objectForKey:@"Subtitle"];

cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
return cell;
```

**thumbnails** is an Array. So When you retrieve the data from Array, Use `[thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` .

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/oaIDcCaML i am getting this error wen i am trying to do so

Comment: "thumbnails" is a Array or Dictionary?

Comment: Give a ; mark after your cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]   . There is no ; mark

Comment: thumbnails = [dict objectForKey:@"Subtitle"];   will this line make thumbnails an array or dictionary ?

Comment: According to me I am taking thumbnails as an Array

Comment: Ok , take thumbnails as as Array and cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[thumbnails objectAtIndex:1]];

Comment: i am not sure wats happening to thumbnails..whether it is a dictionary or array. as in p list i have created one dictionary and inside it two arrays

Comment: Good. U are taking thumbnails, but u don't know what is it ? :)

Comment: i dont know dats y i asked here

Comment: U taking or not thumbnails ? So u know what is it. Then what is tableData ?